# How to build admin panel with user management, pages, general setting etc with laravel 5.3.9?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, admin

I have just started using laravel and could install and set up controller and view.

For a website we need admin panel to manage general setting, pages, blogs, user management and many more things as per the need of a website. Do we need to create each and every section manually (controller, views). If yes then this is time consuming right? Or is there any build in something like plugin.

Can anyone help in this so that I can go accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should package available free on web. This is the site where you can find laravel admin package's there is also documentation and guide for every package http://packalyst.com/

Comment: Thanks @sunnykashyap for the link.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you try laraadmin?

https://github.com/dwijitsolutions/laraadmin

The package will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thank you @moraya.re. I tried to install package. It was successfully installed, tables are created but admin didn't work, I will have a look on it or may be I will contact to the author.

Comment: @user75472 you're welcome :-)

Comment: Hi, @user75472. Do you see any error message on page or in log for LaraAdmin Package. LaraAdmin is 5.2 only as of now. We are working for 5.3 now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to resource folder make one folder ex admin inside that add your file admin.blade.php

now to can use aby of the bootsrap theme and use blank.html file and include it 
for ex: 
            admin.blade.php
                
             
              yield('title');
            
           
            yield('content');
           
        
             now make another file ex 
           index.blade.php

```
       @extends('admin.admin');
            and here u can customise ur admin what all u require
```

Comment: Thanks @rupesh. I have done this and it works. I wanted a solution that will not be time consuming as this one

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column `role` in users table to differentiate the admin and users. And then create a `AdminController.php` in App/http/middleware similar to authenticate.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if($request->user()->role=='Admin')
        {
           return $next($request);
        }
         return redirect('/');    
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

You can protect the user management, pages, general setting etc. now within Adminmiddleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\Adminmiddleware']], function () {
        // Admin routes here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @sanzeeb. I will give it a try as this has used middleware which I haven't tried yet